# Local network between VM and board

Tags: networking, vmware

I am working with VMware and want to create a local network between my VM and a board I am working with a USB-C (VM side) to ethernet (board side) adapter.

I have tried possible network options on VMware but nothing seems to work. I just want to have a small network 192.168.7.0/24 with both my board (192.168.7.101) and VM (192.168.7.100) for some client firmware installation purposes.

For information, I tried the following :

1. Using a LAN segment with my 2 devices only (didn't do it), the board is already configured, so I set the network parameters of the VM and plugged the USB-c directly to it, but nop.
2. Configured a bridged network passing through the host through the adapter, and gave it as a custom network to my VM, didn't work too.

Comment: Is the adapter passed through to the VM as a USB device, or is it handled by the host (VMware)?

Comment: I can do both when using a bridged connexion, either connect it to host or to VM.

Comment: *I can do both when using a bridged connexion, either connect it to host or to VM* No, you don't, you don't understand how it works. In that scenario it's handled by the host; what the guest "sees" is a virtual connection (BTW, that's how you spell it, try enabling spellcheck next time).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. For now, I am trying a bridged connection and connecting the adapter to the host (xD sorry for the mistake), I also added the board to the network. I changed IPs according to my need (gave a random one to host),.
The host is able to ping both targets (VM and board), but they cannot ping each-other (weirdly it worked once like magic and stopped), and cannot ping host either.
Traceroute gives a bunch of stars (* * *), any clues ? is this a good way to do ? (because honnestly I am no network pro but I have to do this). Thanks